# Redbean remove entries from sharedList

Tags: redbean

I am using RedBean and i want to remove the relationships existing at sharedList. Right now i am using

```
$bean->sharedList = array();
R::store($bean);
```

But it does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As per RedBean documentation

> A shared list contains beans that may be associated with more than
>   just one other bean (many-to-many relation).

```
list($vase, $lamp) = R::dispense('product', 2);

$tag = R::dispense( 'tag' );
$tag->name = 'Art Deco';

//creates product_tag table!
$vase->sharedTagList[] = $tag;
$lamp->sharedTagList[] = $tag;
R::storeAll( [$vase, $lamp] );
```

In your code you are not sharing it with any other list. Would you share what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The property containing the collection needs to have the name of a bean type in it;

e.g.

```
$class->sharedStudent = array();
R::store($class);
```

This will remove the relationship between the $class bean and any *student* beans it was previously related to. The *student* beans will not be deleted however.

Your example would only work if the shared bean type was of type 'list' (which I doubt it is.)

Incidentally, you don't need to add 'List' onto the end of a shared collection any more. This was deprecated a few versions back, near the beginning of Redbean 4 I believe.